# ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails 4 . I am using `time_select` to display time in my views. 
While creating new event object I am getting error like:

```
ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors (1 error(s) on assignment of
 multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [12, 15] to time_begin
 (Missing Parameter - time_begin(1))]):
```

In views:

```
<%= f.time_select :time_begin, :ampm => true, include_blank: true, :disabled => true %>
```

In my controller:

I have tried like this way:

```
   params = event_params
   hours = params['time_begin(4i)']
   minutes = params['time_begin(5i)']
   date = Date.strptime(params[:event_start], "%Y-%m-%d")
   date = DateTime.civil(date.year,date.month, date.day, hours.to_i, minutes.to_i, 0, 0)
   params[:time_begin] = date

   @event = Event.new(params)

   private 
   def event_params
     params.require(:event).permit(:time_begin)
   end
```

Comment: your form select field for time_begin has :disabled => true.

Comment: What type is `time_begin` field in the database? This error usually happens when you are trying to assign time value to datetime field. You can find it out with running this in console: `object.column_for_attribute(:time_begin).type`.

Comment: yes date_time  @BroiSatse  can you please what is the other way to store time ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your database field to be of type `time` not `date_time`. The following migration should do:

```
def up
  change_column :events, :time_begin, :time
end

def down
  change_column :events, :time_begin, :datetime
end
```

Note, that both types are stored same way in the database, the difference is that rails will purge (or rather reassign) its date part when you specify column to be a time. This unfortunately means that you will be able to call `start_time.day`, but the returned value will have no true meaning (always one), which might be a little misleading.